# Backing up PostgreSQL - being prompted for password

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql, database-backup

OS: Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 LTS

PostgreSQL Version: 9.5.4

I am trying to set up automatic database backups on my server, and every time I run `pg_dump`, it tells me that no password was supplied. Here's the command I'm using to test:

```
pg_dump --host $DB_HOST --port 5432 --username $DB_USER --no-password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file ~/backups/postgresql/test.backup $DB_NAME
```

All of my environment variables are working just fine. To supply PostgreSQL with the password, I've created a `.pgpass` file in `~/.pgpass`. Here's what it looks like:

> # hostname:port:database:username:password $DB_HOST:5432:$DB_NAME:$DB_USER:$DB_PASS

The file has `0600` permissions, as specified in the [guide](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-pgpass.html). Yet, for some reason, it's not using the password whenever I run `pg_dump`. I've looked at other answers and multiple guides online but still can't figure out what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You do realize that you need to have literal values in `~/.pgpass`, not shell variables like `$DB_HOST`? It's not entirely clear from how you wrote your question.

Comment: I actually did not know that. Thank you for the clarification! Is there a way I can use environment variables in the file?

Comment: No. But you can use environment variables `$PGDATABASE` `$PGPASSWORD` etc and don't need `.pgpass` at all. See [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-envars.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have literal values in `~/.pgpass`, not shell variables like `$DB_HOST`.

If you need environment variables then you can use these supported by libpq (PostgreSQL client library) like `$PGDATABASE` or `$PGPASSWORD`. There are [many others](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/libpq-envars.html). You won't need `~/.pgpass` at all is you use them.

Comment: Thank you very much; this worked beautifully! I decided to hardcode the values into my `~/.pgpass` file.